# exec('script.ps1') returns error, cmd> scrtipt.ps1 runs success

Tags: php, postgresql, powershell, odbc

I have a little PowerShell script to get remote disk space and save this to a table on a Postgre DB.

If I execute the command on the windows cmd it runs successfull.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\xampp\....\skripts\getDiskSpace.ps1 -Command -arg 192.168.178.178
```

But if I use PHP exec() function I get a odbc error

```
exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -File C:\\xampp\\....\\skripts\\getDiskSpace.ps1 -Command -arg 192.168.178.178", $output);
```

---

If I use the PHP escapeshellarg() function, the $output of exec() is NULL

---

The content of $output is:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

I dont know why, I specify the ODBC Driver with

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};Server=$dbServer;Port=5432;Database=$dbName;Uid=$dbUser;Pwd=$dbPass;"
```

The PostgreSQL x64 ODBC driver is installed!

I work on a Windows 2008 SP2 Enterprise Server......(want to get back a linux webserver :D...)

Has somebody problems like this? Or knows the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact dynamically with a real Powershell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shellObj    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('powershell');

$strCmd1   = 'get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk';
$return1   = $shellObj->exeCmd($strCmd1);
```

The return will give you the command return OR error from powershell, just as if you sat at the console. Then parse it in PHP and insert.

Furthermore, you can issue any command you like against the $shellObj, the environment is maintained throughout the life of the PHP script. So instead of bundling commands in a script file, just issue them one by one using the exeCmd() method, that way you can also handle the return and any exceptions.